# How to Print to a Local Printer from the Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, printing, windows-8.1

I have the following scenario:

I have a local printer connected to my Windows 8.1 PC and I would like to print several documents (files with the .txt, .pdf and .doc extensions), from the Command Prompt.

I have tried using the print command documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). However, it doesn't work. I get no stuff being printed and an error message that says:

> "Unable to initialize device DeviceName"

It doesn't matter if I specify the port where the printer is connected or the PC name followed by the printer name.

Is this command still supported in Windows 8.1? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just for my education, why exactly would anyone do this?

Comment: You don't specify if you're trying to print to a local or to a network printer. If thru a network printer, `print` won't work unless you map it to a local port. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775908(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Sickest I imagine some kind of script that collects various system metrics and prints a physical document would require this command.

Comment: @JSanchez I have mentioned the following: "I have a local printer connected to my Windows 8.1 PC".

Comment: My bad. Old age, my friend. Check the answer. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with VBScript. Based on an [answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542272/print-pdf-from-vbscript-or-command-line-without-acrobat-exe) by Jobbo.

The catch is, you *must* have a program registered as the default handler. In other words, if you just type the name of a file from the command line, it should open in the appropriate program. For example, if you pass the argument of "file.pdf" you must have a PDF viewer installed. If you want to print a Word document, you must have Word (I think a viewer *should* work, but I didn't test that) installed.

One more thing, some programs leave a window open (Adobe Acrobat Reader X) after the document prints. You could add logic to the script to close it, but I'll leave that up to you.

To use, type in `cscript /nologo <name_of_script.vbs> <name_of_file_to_print>` where `<name_of_script.vbs>` is the name of the program you save this under, and `<name_of_file_to_print>` is the name of the file you would like to print. If the path contains spaces, enclose the argument in quotes.

```
Option Explicit

Dim shl, objFS
Dim fldr
Dim files,file
Dim file_to_print,wrk_folder

Set shl = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if not wscript.Arguments.Count = 1 then 
    wscript.echo "Missing parameter!"
    wscript.quit
end if

file_to_print = wscript.arguments(0)
file_to_print = objFS.GetAbsolutePathName(file_to_print)
wrk_folder = objFS.GetParentFolderName(file_to_print) & "\"

wscript.echo "Argument passed: " & wscript.arguments(0)
wscript.echo "Absolute file path: " & file_to_print
wscript.echo "Work folder: " & wrk_folder & vbcrlf

if objFS.FileExists(file_to_print) then
    Set fldr = shl.Namespace(wrk_folder)
    Set files = fldr.Items

    For Each file in files
      If LCase(file.Path) = LCase(file_to_print) Then
        file.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
      End If

    Next
end if

Set shl = Nothing
Set fldr = Nothing
Set files = Nothing
Set objFS = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PRINT.COM` command only works with text files.  It will print anything that is pure text, such as .TXT, .INI, .BAT, etc.

If your program supports [print to file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/print-to-file#1TC=windows-7), you can use the `PRINT.COM` command to send those files to your printer.