# Windows "Print" context menu

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, context-menu

I want to print PDF silently on Windows 10.
I found that in PDF there is a context-menu with "Print" option working as I wish. How can I find and reproduce in a command line this command?

Maybe I can do the same using Acrobat command line, but this command should work also with other PDF readers and I cannot be sure that Acrobat is installed in my client.

Comment: Have you tried [print](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/print) command? It is used for background printing.

Comment: I think it is only for COM/LPT or shared printers, I need to print to default printer (maybe local printer)

Comment: Answer provided by JSanchez against [this](https://superuser.com/questions/719551/how-to-print-to-a-local-printer-from-the-command-prompt) question may help. However, you may need to make few changes per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Adobe Reader you may try this syntax :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t  file.pdf "my printer-name"
```